# Image of $\{z:|\mathfrak{Re}(z)|<1\}$ under $f$

Tags: complex-analysis

If I have a set of complex numbers, $S=\{z:|\mathfrak{Re}(z)|<1\}$ and I apply the mapping
$$f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$$
$$f(z)=(1+i)z+1$$
How can I write the image set?  I know that the original set $S$ is the open strip of complex numbers whose real value is between (but not including) $-1$ and $1$.  I know that the image of the line $x=1$ is the line $y=-x+3$ and the image of the line $x=-1$ is the line $y=-x-1$.  So is it as simple as just writing
$$f(S)=\{z:-x-1<y<-x+3\}$$
I can't think of a better way to write this.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but the argument is not rigorous.

Comment: Yes, that's one good way to write it. $$f(S) = \left\{ z : \left\lvert\Re \frac{(1-i)(z-1)}{2}\right\rvert < 1\right\}$$ is another.

Comment: @DanielFischer, how did you get that?

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven I mistyped (fixed now).

Comment: I'm still not sure how you get that...